# В Bootstrap верстке на малых устройствах все поля в 2 колонки

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем привет,
В куске бутстрап кода где на средних и крупных устройствах все поля в 2 колонки :

```
        <form role="form" class="col s12" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/tmp_csvp/edit/1" method="post"
                          accept-charset="utf-8" id="form_tmp_csvp_edit" name="form_tmp_csvp_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">




                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6  ">
                                <label for="id" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Id</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control integer_input validate" value="1" id="id" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6 " >
                                <label for="lender_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Lender name <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control string_input validate" value="DATA SERVICING CORPORATION, INC." id="lender_name" name="lender_name" maxlength="255">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6  ">
                                <label for="borrower_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Borrower name<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control string_input validate" value="WEST GATE APARTMENTS NEW, LTD" id="borrower_name" name="borrower_name" maxlength="255">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6  ">
                                <label for="project_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Project name<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control string_input validate" value="WEST GATE APARTMENTS" id="project_name" name="project_name" maxlength="255">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

     ...
```

предполагается, что на малых устройствах все поля будут в 1 колонку - но этого нет ...
Я что-то упустил ?

Спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

Для правильной работы на мобильных устройствах необходимо добавить `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />`

следовательно код должен выглядеть подобным образом [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkd25h2g/)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>


        <form role="form" class="col s12" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/tmp_csvp/edit/1" method="post"
                          accept-charset="utf-8" id="form_tmp_csvp_edit" name="form_tmp_csvp_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6  ">
                                <label for="id" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Id</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control integer_input validate" value="1" id="id" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6 " >
                                <label for="lender_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Lender name <span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control string_input validate" value="DATA SERVICING CORPORATION, INC." id="lender_name" name="lender_name" maxlength="255">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6  ">
                                <label for="borrower_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Borrower name<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control string_input validate" value="WEST GATE APARTMENTS NEW, LTD" id="borrower_name" name="borrower_name" maxlength="255">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6  ">
                                <label for="project_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Project name<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input class="form-control string_input validate" value="WEST GATE APARTMENTS" id="project_name" name="project_name" maxlength="255">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я выложил в онлайн :
[ref](http://ec2-34-212-140-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/csvp/public/tmp_csvp/edit/1)

прописан в заголовке файла
и поэтому на очень маленьких устройствах все поля/лейблы складываются с новой строки как и нужно
https://imgur.com/a/x6Mkw

На ipad-ах имея блок

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6  ">
        <label for="id" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Id</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control integer_input validate" value="1" id="id" readonly="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6 ">
        <label for="lender_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label">Кредитор
            <span class="required"> * </span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control string_input validate" value="DATA SERVICING CORPORATION, INC." id="lender_name" name="lender_name" maxlength="255">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я полагал что два блока полей(Id,lender_name) будут расположены с новых строк, но нет:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhZwG.jpg

Что я упустил ?